# What is the Botez gambit?

Tags: terminology, famous-players

A friend of mine told me about this term used when you lose your queen, the Botez gambit, named after Alexandra Botez. It seems this term has arrived to casual, not necessarily young, (on-line) players like my friend, and has gone beyond the anglophone world.

The term has been adapted into [Spanish](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjEyebX7pv3AhUug_0HHTJkAekQFnoECBsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fpost%2FUgkxNbZMVEw4foQdpbOebtn6sHr3EoOXJh8d&usg=AOvVaw2_6ZRfVNvvh0-vdEAbGpco) (*gambito Botez*), [Portuguese](https://pt.quora.com/No-xadrez-o-que-%C3%A9-o-Botez-gambit) (*gambito Botez*), [French](https://www.chess.com/fr/news/view/chess-com-lance-son-nouvel-outil-vue-densemble-affichant-toutes-vos-stats) (*gambit Botez*), [Catalan](https://www.racocatala.cat/forums/fil/238961/escacs-el-gambit-botez) (*gambit Botez*). In Italian, [the English term seems to be used](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjR17Pu8Jv3AhWO4YUKHX0PDbkQwqsBegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DZ5qP94J1aIY&usg=AOvVaw3nFjT8BfOjudorrAwj9S9a).

When exactly do you use this term? Where does it come from?

Comment: Also, why ask the question? Because there's more to it than what I say in the question, and I think it would be interesting to have a proper answer on the site.

Answer (score 12):

**Botez Gambit:** A joke term for when you give away your Queen, intentionally or unintentionally, without adequate compensation (also known as blundering your Queen).

According to [Brian Towers♦](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39690/what-is-the-botez-gambit#comment64046_39690), GM [Ben Finegold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Finegold) "coined the term after a long match against WFM [Alexandra Botez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandra_Botez) in which she routinely gave her queen away when the time pressure got to her." However, a Chess.com [article](https://www.chess.com/terms/botez-gambit-chess) claims it was viewers of the [BotezLive Twitch channel](https://www.twitch.tv/botezlive) that created the meme term.

GM [Hikaru Nakamura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hikaru_Nakamura) has an entire speedrun series dedicated to this ([see Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBAghpuH4gs), or [view all the games](https://www.chess.com/member/ohno_mybotezgambit)). In his description, he denotes the Botez Gambit as blundering and/or hanging the Queen.

<sub>The answer is already [in the question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/revisions/39690/1) so I am making this a community wiki.</sub>